# How to compare array of objects and return an array of object with match and non match key value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**This is my Array Of Object i want to filter data with match and non-match key value and store in array.  how i compare this array of object**

```
      const data = [{
        overview: {
          "Engine type": "F8D",
          "Max Power (PS @ rpm)": "47.99 @ 6000",
          "Overall length (mm)": "3445",
          "Overall width (mm)":
            "1490 (without side moulding) / 1515 (with side moulding)",
          "Overall height (mm)": "1475",
          "ABS with EBD": "Yes"
        }
        car_id: "119",
        model_cd: "Alto",
      },
      {
        overview: {
          "Max Power (PS @ rpm)": "54 @ 5678",
          "Overall length (mm)": "3429",
          "Overall width (mm)": "1560",
          "Overall height (mm)": "1541",
          "ABS with EBD": "Yes",
          "Daylight Running Lamps": "Yes"
        },
        car_id: "129",
        model_cd: "Redi-GO",
        model_desc: "Redi-GO",
      }
    ];
```

My Expected result like Below

```
[
overview{
      "Engine type": "F8D",
      "Max Power (PS @ rpm)": "54 @ 5678",
      "Overall length (mm)": "3429",
      "Overall width (mm)": "1560",
      "Overall height (mm)": "1541",
      "ABS with EBD": "Yes",
      "Daylight Running Lamps": "Yes"
}
]
```

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify what steps you have tried. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It may also help to clarify the relationship between the two parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using jQuery Extend: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Example:

```js
const myData = [{
    overview: {
      "Engine type": "F8D",
      "Max Power (PS @ rpm)": "47.99 @ 6000",
      "Overall length (mm)": "3445",
      "Overall width (mm)": "1490 (without side moulding) / 1515 (with side moulding)",
      "Overall height (mm)": "1475",
      "ABS with EBD": "Yes"
    },
    car_id: "119",
    model_cd: "Alto",
  },
  {
    overview: {
      "Max Power (PS @ rpm)": "54 @ 5678",
      "Overall length (mm)": "3429",
      "Overall width (mm)": "1560",
      "Overall height (mm)": "1541",
      "ABS with EBD": "Yes",
      "Daylight Running Lamps": "Yes"
    },
    car_id: "129",
    model_cd: "Redi-GO",
    model_desc: "Redi-GO",
  }
];

function combine(key, data) {
  var temp = {};
  temp[key] = {};
  $.each(data, function(i, el) {
    // Merge myData Item into temp Object
    temp[key] = $.extend(temp[key], el[key]);
  });
  return [temp];
}

console.log(combine("overview", myData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```